# C++: Getting SIGCONT error for memory misallocation

Tags: c++

This is the code for which I am getting SIGCONT error for large inputs on the CodeChef online IDE. However, in VS Code it works just fine.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

typedef long long ll;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    ll T, a, b, c;
    cin >> T;

    while(T--)
    {
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        ll arr[3] = {a, b, c};

        int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
        sort(arr, arr + size);

        cout << arr[1] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The SIGCONT error represents memory misallocation, but I don't know how to fix it in C++. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Note: VS Code is just an editor. Code doesn’t “work” in it, fine or not. There’s a compiler under there and an OS running it that may matter. Also the first three lines are considered bad, I would suggest not using those.

Comment: Can you add the input for which it's failing?

Comment: To use std::cout you need to \#include <iostream> and to use std::sort you need to \#include <algorithm>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeChef IDE evidently sends your running program SIGCONT whenever your program runs for too long. For example, I simplified your program to the following (which should be clear is an "infinite" loop):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    long long T = -1;
    while (T--) {
        cin >> x;
        cout << x << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problems with this program are:

1. The while loop never breaks. If the initial value of T is negative, then the while loop condition is treated as true since it is nonzero. Then T is continuously decremented, so it continues to be true for an indeterminate amount of time.
2. There is no error checking on reading from std::cin. If there is no more input, the value of x will be uninitialized, i.e. it will be whatever value was there before, or an uninitialized value if it was never written at least once.

> The SIGCONT error represents memory misallocation ...

No. CodeChef documents a few status codes like this: https://www.codechef.com/wiki/status-codes

According to that documentation, SIGSEGV represents a memory problem. SIGCONT is not documented.